# MS Exchange connection has stopped working

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

A friend helped me install and setup Small Business Server 2011 a couple years ago. I have outlook on my PC which connects to Exchange on my server. Outlook (2010) recently began saying it was offline, then when I closed it and reopened it, it says it can't connect to the server. Last week, I ran the compaction routine on Outlook and it seems that the problem may have begun then.

Any ideas on how I can get Outlook connected to my Exchange server again? By the way, I can connect to Exchange from my laptop with Outlook using HTTP and via a web browser using OWA.

Comment: Compaction routine what exactly is that?

Comment: It's something you run within Outlook (just a button in a menu) that reduces the size of the PST file. Just a simple maintenance routine. It may not have anything to do with the problem, but I thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: Why use the term compaction why not simply state you ran the "compact now" routine on the archive PST which by the way would not effect the file that the Exhange connection would use

Comment: Outlook has been around for many years and there are many versions with all types of nuances. What version of the client are you running? Are there any error messages on the Exchange server?

Comment: Outlook version is 2010. Where on the server should I look? Just the Event Log? Is there other valuable info Exchange provides?